# Is the Python Module Counter() Using C?

Tags: python, counter, python-import, python-c-api

When I use the function:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Is Counter() sourced using C structures? Is there any convenient way to determine that generally for this and other function?

Give that Python is open sourced generally what should I be looking for in the source code if it is the best way to determine if a given function uses C structures?

Comment: See for yourself: [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py). The best way of telling is by looking at the documentation.

Comment: it looks not :(

Comment: having trouble looking at the source code to know what to look for

Comment: Since CPython is a C program, ultimately everything "uses C structures". It is just a question of how far you have to dig before you encounter the underlying C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to assert this for classes, but there's a way to determine if a function or method was written in C. So any class written in C probably defines at least one explicit or implicit function in C (if not it will be difficult) and you can check with [`inspect.isbuiltin`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isbuiltin):

```
>>> import collections
>>> import inspect
>>> def is_c_class(cls):
...     return any(inspect.isbuiltin(getattr(cls, methname, None)) 
...                for methname in cls.__dict__)

>>> is_c_class(collections.Counter)
False

>>> is_c_class(dict)
True
```

However that's not all there is to it because `collections.Counter` calls `collections._count_elements` which is a C function:

```
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(collections._count_elements)
True
```

So you should always check the source code ([Pythons repository is on github](https://github.com/python/cpython) and also the implementation for [`Counter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L452)) to be sure.

---

Note that the above mentioned check using `isbuiltin` has some flaws. For example you could have a class attribute that is a C function:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     c_function = all  # builtin all function is a C function

>>> is_c_class(Test)
True
```

So don't rely on it always giving correct results, treat it as approximation.

Comment: You can actually check a class's `__flags__` to see if it's written in C - a class implemented through the C API won't have Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE set - but the value of Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE isn't exposed anywhere at the Python level. (It's currently 1 << 9, but I don't know if that's stable.)

Comment: @user2357112 Good point, I actually looked at the flags and dismissed them after there values weren't given explicitly.